# How to Build + Run an Android app with Ant on Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant

With some hassle, I've managed to tell Eclipse to build an Android app using Ant in debug mode, then call ProGuard to shrink it before producing the APK.
I want that because my project [became too big](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) and I needed a way to delete unused methods also when debugging.

Now, if I click on *Project -> Build Project* I finally see the Ant output and, at the end, I have an optimized APK file on the *bin* folder.

There is a last thing I need. Before all of this, I just had to click on [the "build" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzHAx.jpg) on Eclipse to create a non-optimized build then run it on my test device. Now that everything changed, if I click on it, Eclipse tries to build and run my app but **without using Ant**.

So, I want to be able to click on the green button and start this process:

Build with Ant -> Generate optimized APK -> run it on device

For now, I can reach the end of the second step, but I can't run it directly from Ecplise. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Is it something related to the menu entry *Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration... -> Ant Build* ?

Comment: Are we talking about a new project or an existing one that you want to import? In case it's a new project: Why still using Eclispe for Android development, instead of Android Studio? Don't get me wrong, I don't wanna start a Pepsi/Coke discussion, but you'll save yourself A LOT of hassle if you switch to AS and gradle.

Comment: It's an existing Eclipse project that I edited to enable Ant.